# Keywords and PACS classification in Latex article class

Tags: keywords

I'm writing an article in the `article` class and I need to put `\keywords{}` and `\pacs{}`  classification inside the `\maketitle` enviroment. Are there any package that would help me to do that?

Comment: `\keywords` and `\pacs` aren't defined by default in `article`.  Either you will have to manually redefine `\maketitle` or use a different class which is designed with commands like `\pacs` such as [`revtex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1).  If this is an article to be submitted to a journal then it may be worth looking at how that journal requests submissions to be prepared, often they will specify or provide a specific class.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the greetings from your message, because, on this site, it is not customary to include them in question.  [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) is the usual way to thank someone who helps you.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, Understood.

Comment: @DaiBowen is right about finding out which class the journal wants, but if you really do need this in `article`, you do not need to redefine `\maketitle` manually. The `titling` package almost certainly would support what you need, given suitable definitions for `\keywords` and `\pacs`, of course.

Comment: @DaiBowen, Yes, I really need them on an {article} class. How can I make a command for this?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example showing how you are defining `\keywords` and `\pacs` or at least what kind of content you need them to have. `\keywords` is fine, but I've no idea about `\pacs`.

Comment: @cfr `\pacs` will be pretty much the same as `\keywords`.  PACS are the [Physics and Astronomy Classification Scheme](https://publishing.aip.org/publishing/pacs) which tag the fields an article is relevant to.  They seem to have been abandoned by AIP and APS in the last few years though.

Comment: @DaiBowen I guessed it must be discipline specific.

Comment: @cfr Right now, this question is unclear. Especially looking at the other questions of the OP. Thoughts?

Comment: @Johannes_B Close as unclear, I guess. If the OP was still interested, I take it they'd have added an MWE, since they've provided such things for other questions. 'Abandoned while unclear' seems the most apt description.